# ExcelWriter Has No Output

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to used ExcelWriter to replace/update a sheet in an excel workbook with a dataframe read in from another file. If I just use `df.to_excel()` to write the file out it works as expected, but I want to keep all other sheets in the receiving workbook as well.

I've tried a few different iterations of the code below but no matter what I do if I use ExcelWriter then my receiving file is not updated or modified at all.

**Note:** 
The sheet I'm trying to update already exists if that makes a difference. Maybe my tkinter widgets are messing with the process but as mentioned the process works for a simple df.to_excel() command.

**Code:**

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import xlrd
import pandas as pd



def openMasterFile():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    global masterfile
    masterfile =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\Users\\...",
                                             title = "Select master file", parent=root)
    root.destroy()

#open new data
def openNewFile():
    root=Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    global newfile
    newfile =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:\\Users\\...",
                                          title = "Select new file", parent=root)
    root.destroy()



openMasterFile()
openNewFile()

data = pd.read_excel(newfile, "Partners")

book = openpyxl.load_workbook(masterfile)
with pd.ExcelWriter(masterfile,  engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Partners", engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)
    writer.save()
```